# Appointment database with resources and providers

Tags: database-design

i want to design a database schema for an appointment scheduling application. An objective is to keep the application as generic as possible in order to allow multiple use-case scenarios. I'm currently thinking about a design decision and need some advice.

An *appointment* can use zero, one ore more *resources* (i.e. a conference room, table, seat, …) and also has zero or one *provider* (i.e. a consultant, lawyer, doctor, …).

Both *resources* and *providers* have several things in common. So both a *resource* and a *provider* are located in a specific *location* and adhere to zero, one or more *schedules*. But they also differ: e.g. a *provider* can offer zero, one or more *services*, whereas a *resource* can not. Of course both types have different attribute types.

So I somehow need to unify *resource* and *provider* otherwise it will result in a bad design. For example a *schedule* needs a nullable foreign key to *resource* as well as to *provder*. Same with *location*. Another solution would be to use some kind of inheritance (*provider* inherits from *resource*). This would be okay since I will use an ORM anyway but I assume there is a better/cleaner approach.

The solution could also differ from my proposal completely, but has to fulfill the following use-cases:

- **Consultant appointment**: A user can first select the desired service/-s, and than can choose from a list of consultants (*providers*) with possibly different *locations* that offer the selected service/-s. In the last step she can choose a appointment based on the *provider's* schedule and already existing *appointments*.
- **Table reservation**: A user can choose a desired date and time and than can see all free tables (*resources*) at this specific point in time, dependent on their *schedule* and other *appointments*.
- **Mixed scenario**: It should be possible to mix these scenarios as desired. For example one could also choose from resources when consulting a consultant (i.e. choosing from different sized conference rooms). Or one could choose the waitress when booking a table (does not make a lot of sense in this example, but there might be scenarios were feasible).

So question is, what would be the best and cleanest design to model these scenarios.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You want to have a situation where all of your appointments (bookings, reservations) are **easy to keep in one place**.  The reason that you want all of these in one place is that in order to find gaps (openings) and to confirm that a new appointment does not conflict with existing ones, you're going to want to use the standard date/time overlap test, which will look something like this:

```
// Look for the absence of any overlapping appointments...
// SELECT whatever from wherever, then start filtering for appointment collisions...
AND WHERE NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT A.AppointmentID
  FROM dbo.Appointment A
  WHERE A.StartDateTime <= @ProposedAppointmentEndDateTime
    AND A.EndDateTime >= @ProposedAppointmentStartDateTime
  )
// ... etc.
```

If you have to have this kind of collision detection logic against appointments in two separate tables (one for `RESOURCES` and one for `PROVIDERS`) then your SQL gets much uglier in a hurry.

Using **Entity Subtyping** is a common and generally accepted practice for achieving this kind of simplification.  The hardest part is going to be naming.  What is the superset of *resources* and *providers*?  Is it a *ReservableThing*?  That's not a great name, on the other hand, it is descriptive.  If your business doesn't have a widely accepted term for it, then maybe a system-ish term is OK, since it will mostly be read in your code rather than in your GUI, in all likelihood.